# Using Delegated and Protocols to return data from dataTaskWithRequest in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I have a framework which calls an API which returns a JSON back to me. The problem is that I have a function inside my SDK which uses NSURLSession and calls DataTaskWithRequest to fetch the data. The issue is my function returns the value even before the Data is fetched properly. I have tried using Completion Handler with DataTaskWithRequest and currently using a while loop to wait for the data to be received. Is there any other possible way to do it

Code

```
public func getDetails() -> AnyObject {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        received = false
        let baseUrl = "API_URL  Here"
        let url = NSURL(string: baseUrl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        print("Starting the connection")
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler : {
            (data, response, error ) in

            //Proper JSON Form

            do
            {
                self.JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error")
                return
            }

            self.received = true

        })
        task.resume()

        print("Going through the loop")
        while(!received)
        {
            print("Searching")
        }
        print(JSON)
            return JSON
    }
    else
    {

        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
        return 0

    }
}
```

Comment: post your code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are attempting to turn something asynchronous into something synchronous. To summarize in pseudo code, you are doing this:-

```
let myData = getDetails(blah)
doSomeAction(myData)
```

The way to approach it is to use the completion block as the indicator itself and make everything asynchronous.
*This code has not been tested*

```
public typealias CompletionHandler = (success: Bool, message: String, json: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> Void

func getDetailsAsync(completion: CompletionHandler) {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        received = false
        let baseUrl = "API_URL  Here"
        let url = NSURL(string: baseUrl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        print("Starting the connection")
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler : {
            (data, response, error ) in

            //Proper JSON Form
            if error != nil {
                completion(false, "error", nil, error)
            }
            else {
                do
                {
                    self.JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
                    completion(true, "OK", self.JSON, nil)
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error")
                    completion(false, "JSON parsing failed", nil, nil)
                }
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }
    else {
        completion(false, "No network", nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
getDetailsAsync() {
    (success, message, json, error) in 
    if success == true {
        print(json)

    }
    else {
        // Do your alert here
        print(message)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104758/nsurlsession-doesnt-return-data-in-first-call/36104903#36104903) answer might be helpful.

Comment: Thank You! Solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use another thread to monitor the process and get it to send a message thru your protocol.

```
newQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation(block: {


        })

    operation2.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 2 completed")
    }

    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation(block: {


        })

    operation1.completionBlock = {

        self.newQueue.addOperation(operation2)
    }

    operation1.qualityOfService  = .UserInitiated
    newQueue.addOperation(operation1)
}
```

Here is a outline of the code. In short you launch your session with block 1 and on completion launch your verification of the download with block2. block1 fires block2 when it completes [almost immediately as you say], but block 2 doesn't fire until the data structure being completed in block 1 is downloaded.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit further not familiar with threading in swift

Comment: It is quite straight forward Singh. All I am doing here is writing code that no longer flows from top to bottom, but op1 to op2. So addOperation starts op1, when it completes, it fires its completion block which in then adds operation2 which runs and then fires its completion block. You can start your session in operation 1 and monitor its completion when you know it is running in operation 2.

Comment: The quality of service here is a swift 2.0 feature to tell your IOS what the priority of the said process need to be . So I would make operation 2 here as low as possible if your simply monitoring and operation 1 one or two notches higher, check out quality of service is NSOperations.

Comment: I like the approach, will test it